# Drive Node factor with received direct and indirect light on object faces (Cycles)

Tags: lighting, color, shader-nodes

I would like to change the Material of an Object according to the amount of direct light it gets. More specifically, i would like to drive the factor of a mix node displaying red for all faces that do not receive direct light and blue for all the faces that receive direct light. This should only be implemented in the Shader Nodes of an Object, not the light itself as i only want this object to have this property.
Please let me know if i should improve my title for this post or provide more infos. I tried playing around with the Light Path Node but without success.
The face of the plane on the left side receives direct light and should be blue, the face of the plane on the right side does not receive direct light and should be red. Im using Cycles for this.
Best Regards
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Eevee you can use *Shader to RGB* to see the brightness under lightning, and then adjust a threshold to the world lightning, so that you need some additional light in order to pass the threshold, and then based on this threshold being passed or not, choose a color/shader:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. That's a nice trick for Eevee! Sadly i'm working in Cycles so this won't work for me.